# jQuery help - validation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a form that allows the user to input values, for an order form. When the form is loaded, it needs to highlight all the rows that have nothing in them, or where the value is more than 100, then unhighlight them when this is corrected.

Also, there is a submit button - this needs to be disabled when any of the text boxes are highlighted

Here's the code i have so far - does anyone have any ideas?

```
$(':text').focusin(function() {
    var inp = $(this).val();
    if (inp > 100) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    if (inp.length < 1) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    if (inp.length > 0 && inp <= 100) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    }
});

$(':text').change(function() {
    var inp = $(this).val();
    if (inp > 100) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    if (inp.length < 1) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    if (inp.length > 0 && inp <= 100) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    }
});
```

Comment: So, what's not working?  And what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: It's working fine, but i was just wondering if it would be possible to have them pre-highlighted when the form loads

And also to have a submit button disabled if any of them are still highlighted

I think i added the php tag by accident - my bad! Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does the trick nicely, http://jsfiddle.net/fr85u/

HTML

```
<form>
  <input />
  <input value="101"/>
  <input value="99"/>
  <button disabled="disabled"> submit </button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('input').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      val = $this.val();

  if(val > 100 || val === ''){
     $this.addClass('red');
  }
}).on('blur', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      val = $this.val();

  $this.toggleClass('red', val === '' || val > 100);

  $('button').prop('disabled', $("input.red").length > 0);  
});
```

CSS

```
.red{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Ya, I do.  When the inputs are blurred, the button will be either disabled or enabled based on the result of this expression `$("input.red").length > 0`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for your help! It's all working brilliantly!

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget, if this solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation to you would be to add a class (i.e. 'red_bg') to the elements as you are changing them.  This would give you and easy way to to determine when to enable the submit button (i.e. `$('.red_bg').length == 0`).

Something like this should do:

```
function validateField(jqSelector) {
    var inp = jqSelector.val();
    var regex = new RegExp(/^\d+$/);
    if (regex.test(inp) && parseInt(inp) <= 100) {
        $(this).removeClass('red_bg');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('red_bg')
    }
    setSubmit();
}

function setSubmit() {
    $('.red_bg').length == 0) {
        $('#submit_id').removeAttr('disabled');
    }  else {
        $('#submit_id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}


$(function () {
    $(':text').focusin(function() {
        validateField($(this));
    }).change(function() {
        validateField($(this));
    }).each(function() {
        validateField($(this));
    });
});
```

Please note that you might consider the use of more in depth validation as I have shown using regex as right now, you are doing nothing to validate that the values entered are numeric.

Comment: This assumes that the default background-color is white, if not you'll need to explicitly change the else clause to also set the white background (or toggle class to a white background class).  The real takeaways from this answer are to note how the common code has been modularized out into a reusable function, and how the triggers are chained together.

Comment: Updated to include regex to test for all digits entered in input and to do a proper `parseInt` on the input string.

Comment: Updated for latest comment to original question about OP wanting to be able to run this validation on page load.  I wrapped everything in an onready function and utilized `each()` to go through each field and perform the validation up front.

Answer (score 0):

Since your event handler functions do exactly the same, you can rewrite your code to

```
function test() {
    var inp = $(this).val();
    if (inp > 100) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    if (inp.length < 1) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    if (inp.length > 0 && inp <= 100) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    }
};

$(':text').focusin(test).change(test);
test();
```

The second last line attaches the event handler to both events, the last line executes the highlighting function the first time.